# SSRS: Hide items of all export formats

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I followed [this](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/) approach to hide items when exporting to excel, but what if I want to hide all the export formats? the problem is the MHTML format.

How can I hide excel, word, etc AND the MHTML format with a expression?

Comment: Do you want to hide elements depending on renderformat or are you asking to hide the render formats themselves?  (ie so there is no option to export to excel?)

Comment: @trubs I want to hide elements depending on renderformat

Comment: Still a little confused here?  XHTML format?  do you mean MHTML? or XML?  or have I totally missed the point?  (I cant see an export format of XHTML)

Comment: @trubs sorry, fixed, it is MHTML

Comment: did the answer below solve your question?

Comment: @trubs no, please see [this post](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/), the RPL and MHTML formats are true in the RenderFormat.IsInteractive variable; also check [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/730679/globals-renderformat-name-has-inconsistent-behavior-when-used-in-hidden-expression) out

Answer (score 0):

To hide an object for everything except the report viewer you could use the following in the visiblity expression of the object...

```
 =iif(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive
        ,Globals!RenderFormat.Name="MHTML"
        ,true
      )
```

[image]